# A generalization of abelian categories including Grp

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The category of groups shares various properties with abelian categories. For example, the Five lemma and Nine lemma hold in **Grp**. Is there a weakened notion of abelian category which also includes **Grp** such that the 5- and 9- lemmas are still provable by arrow chasing?

Comment: Have a look at exact categories à la Quillen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Semi-abelian categories are good contexts for doing homological algebra, and $\mathbf{Grp}$ is semi-abelian. One of the axioms is the split short five lemma, and the five lemma, nine lemma, and snake lemma are theorems. A category is abelian if and only if it is semi-abelian *and* its opposite is semi-abelian.

Comment: Does the snake lemma hold in **Grp**? I didn't think so...

Comment: Yes, it does, though one has to be more careful with the statement. See [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2000.8526).

Comment: Reference: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Borceux-Bourn

Answer (score 1):

Try with regular categories, there are still some "exactness" property and similar stuff ( moreover you can always embed such categories in Grothendieck topoi).